# What is the difference between force state :focus and Focus directly from the dropdown?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the "elements" view, upon right-clicking on a specific element, the Google Chrome devtools provide you with two different "focus" options for focusing on the element in the HTML form.

[Force state :focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnD5N.png)

[Focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPSac.png)

What is the difference between them?